# How to profile MS SQL Server database column values using SQL for type of value stored in column

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005, profiling

I have an requirement where i have to profile / check that a paricular column in a MS SQL Server database table contains only characters or not (numbers are not allowed in a column like city etc). Similary i have to check that a column can contain alpha numeric values but not special characters(like @,#,$ etc.). How can this be accomplished using SQL Server sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all rows that contain numbers you can use [Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). `Column like ('%[0-9]%')`
You can extend that to include other unwanted characters. `Column like ('%[0-9,@,#,$]%')`

I have no good solution for the case when you want to specify the *valid* characters and find the rows that is illegal. Here is a solution that first splits the columns so you have one row for each character. Depending on the size of your table this might work for you or it is just too slow.

```
declare @T table (ID int, Name varchar(50))

insert into @T values
(1, 'Name'),
(2, 'Name1'),
(3, '@Name'),
(4, 'Nam3e')

;with CharSplit as 
(
  select
    ID,
    left(Name, 1) as Val,
    stuff(Name, 1, 1, '') as Name
  from @T
  union all
  select
    ID,
    left(Name, 1) as Val,
    stuff(Name, 1, 1, '') as Rest
  from CharSplit
  where Len(Name) > 0
),
InvalidList as
(
  select distinct ID
  from CharSplit
  where Val not between 'a' and 'z'
)
select
  T.ID,
  T.Name
from InvalidList as I
  inner join @T as T
    on I.ID = T.ID
```

Result

```
ID          Name
----------- --------------------------------------------------
2           Name1
3           @Name
4           Nam3e
```

If you are using case sensitive collation you probably need to include `and Val not between 'A' and 'Z'` as well (not tested).

Answer (score 2):

The idea of character splitting [by Mikael Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242199/how-to-profile-ms-sql-server-database-column-values-using-sql-for-type-of-value-s/5242367#5242367) could be implemented differently with the help of a number table:

```
WITH atable AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    VALUES
      (1, 'Name'),
      (2, 'Name1'),
      (3, '@Name'),
      (4, 'Nam3e')
  ) x (ID, Name)
),
atable_split AS (
  SELECT
    t.ID,
    t.Name,
    OneChar = SUBSTRING(t.Name, v.number, 1)
  FROM atable t
    INNER JOIN master..spt_values v
      ON v.type = 'P' AND v.number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(t.Name)
)
SELECT ID, Name
FROM atable_split
GROUP BY ID, Name
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN OneChar BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 1
```

This method produces a better execution plan than what the one by Mikael does, and it may probably be not even the best one either.

Comment: +1 Using a number table is better than recursive cte to split the string.

Answer (score 1):

To provide an example based on what Mikael said:

```
declare @Data table (id int not null primary key identity(1,1), blurb nvarchar(255) , number nvarchar(255) )

insert into @Data( [blurb] , [number] ) values 
 ('Not only Numeric' , '(011) 555-1234')
,('Pure Text'        , 'Test')
,('Good Number'      , '12345')

select * from @Data where number not like '%[^0-9]%' -- Valid Data
select * from @Data where number     like '%[^0-9]%' -- Invalid Data
```